# How to find out that the user's login time has expired in sharepoint with pnp js?

Tags: sharepoint, http-status-code-403, pnp-js

I know when error 403 in a request that's mean user does not have access.
But if the login time expires , again request give error 403.

can you help me?

I looked in other sites but I did not find the answer.

Comment: You did not tell us how can we help you?

Comment: How to find out that the user's login time has expired in sharepoint with pnp js

Comment: The expiration time is written in the token you are using to communicate with sharepoint. But the question looks like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)